# How To Block Chromium Edge from using IE Mode on single page

Tags: microsoft-edge

I do not have access to change company policy that has enabled IE mode for intranet sites.

On one page used by our team, IE cannot be used. Using Edge in IE mode, the page does not work.

There is a 3 minute refresh built into the page with the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180" />
```

After the first refresh, it switches back to normal Chromium Edge mode, and everything works. How do I force this to load in Chromium Edge every time?

I could fix the page to work in IE, but that seems like a huge waste of effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

Can't reproduce the problem on my side, I have created a sample using the above meta tag, after refreshing, it will stay the IE mode or Edge mode.

Generally, there have three ways to enable/disable the internet explorer mode in the Microsoft Edge (Chromium) browser.

1. Users can enable the IE mode by applying the group policy setting.
2. Users can enable the IE mode by enabling the Edge flag in the MS Edge Chromium browser.
3. Users can enable the IE mode using a command-line switch.

If you don't have access to change Edge group policy, you could try to use the second and third method to enable the IE mode in Edge browser.

**Users can enable the IE mode by enabling the Edge flag in the MS Edge Chromium browser.**

(1) Open MS Edge Chromium browser.

(2) Enter **edge://flags/** in the address bar and press Enter key.

(3) Find **Enable IE Integration** using Search flags search box.

(4) Select the **IE mode** option from the dropdown control.

[image]

(5) Restart the MS Edge Chromium browser.

**Users can enable the IE mode using a command-line switch.**

(1) Create a shortcut of the MS Edge Chromium browser.

(2) Then try to **right-click** on the shortcut and go to **properties**.

(3) Go to the **Shortcut** tab.

(4) In the **target** field, try to add **--ie-mode-test** after the path of Edge exe. make sure there is one space between the path and this argument.

[image]

(5) Click on the OK button.

Then, you could click the Edge shortcut (contains "--ie-mode-test") to open the website, click the **Edge settings and more**, in the **More tools** option, you could find the option to enable/disable IE mode.

[image]

Choose "Open sites in Internet Explorer Mode" or "Open sites in Edge Mode" to enable/disable IE mode. After that, the tab will stay in that status.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, the answer was dreadfully simple: Just use another tag to force the browser to use latest IE version installed.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This also "Fixed" IE. It turns out the reason IE wasn't working was that intranet sites were using compatibility mode.

One remaining question is why Edge was switching from IE mode to normal mode after a refresh... Might be a bug?

Comment: Which version of Chromium Edge browser are you using? Do you mean after using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180" />` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`, if refresh the page, it will auto switch from IE mode to the normal Chromium Edge mode? Try to clear the browser data (cache and cookie and so on) and recheck it.

Comment: We are using Edge: Version 81.0.416.68 (Official build) (64-bit) The original behavior prior to adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>` was that it would load the page initially in IE Mode, but then after the automatic page refresh, it would render using the Edge engine. Since adding this tag, it now correctly renders using the Edge engine every time, it is a mostly a moot point- but I have no idea why it was doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by @Zhi Lv - MSFT is outdated(there are no such flags in the newest builds) and thus irellevant. You should try using the latest Dev branch of the browser as they have fixed one bug regarding the IE Mode itself.